# How do I create a div with specific format?

Tags: css

I need to create a div witch will be filled with another image, in the pocket of the image above:
[image]

The image don't have a fixed size, so it needs to be repeated.

Comment: Look at CSS3 transforms, specifically rotate. You'll probably have to put the pockets behind the pants.

Comment: This is the answer. Wanna make it as so, so I can choose it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at CSS3 transforms, specifically `rotate` (possibly using skew, depending on your use case). You'll probably have to put the picture *behind* the pants, in order to get it to be the right shape.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in CSS but I think it would be much easier to use a photo editing software and paste on the images and save it as a new file.

Comment: The problem is that the user need to be able to change the images. Like, for an e-commerce, he can choose the images of the first and the second places. I would need to cut all possible images to fit all possible models..